# i want to add a drop down menu in my existing "contact us" form

Tags: php, html, css, contact-form

i want to add a drop down menu to my form which includes different services.
i want them to choose any one of the value and get me on my email with the other information.

please help me with the changes in the code with respect to my existing code.

Thank you.

the given below is the html code

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
                  <fieldset>
                    <label><input type="text" name="Name" value="Name" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Name' ) this.value=''"></label>
                    <label><input type="text" name="Email" value="Email" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Email'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Email' ) this.value=''"></label>
                    <label><textarea name="Message" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Message'){this.value=''}">Message</textarea></label><br>
                    <a href="#" class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">Send</a></div>
                  </fieldset>                   
                </form>
```

the given below is the css code:

```
#form {margin:8px 0 0 0; width:575px}
#form input {border:#e0e0e1 1px solid; background:#fff;font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000;padding:5px 9px 7px 13px;outline:medium none;width:341px; height:17px; float:left; border-radius:4px}
#form textarea {border:#e0e0e1 1px solid; background:#fff;font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000; height:188px;outline:medium none;overflow:auto;padding:6px 0 0 13px;width:560px;resize:none;margin:0 0 0 0;float:left; border-radius:4px}
#form label {position:relative;overflow:hidden;display:block;min-height:41px}
```

the given below is the php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "jay44556677@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "website html form submissions";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We're sorry, but there's errors found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['Name']) ||
        //!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Email']) ||
        //!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['Name']; // required
    //$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['Email']; // required
    //$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['Message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  //if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    //$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  //}
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    //$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    //$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contacts.html';
    </script>

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: # Insert a <select name="service"> with some <option> elements into your HTML
# Implement the validation and output analog to the other fields in your PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add html code in form to extend dropdown

```
<select name="myOpt">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

use id or name to access in php
"myOpt"